# How to get filename only without .tar.gz in a batch script

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am creating a batch script where I need to define a variable to initiate a docker shell from Windows command prompt.

The script has a user choose their docker image build from their directory but the file is in `.tar.gz` format.

Switching from `%~nxI` to `%~ni` in my script only removes the `.gz`.

Do I need to unzip the file to be able to do this or is there another command to copy the name sans the `.tar` portion to the variable?

```
Pause
cd /images
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A counter=0
set choice=

for /R %%i in (iac_*.tar.gz) do (
    if not "%%~ni" == "%~nx0" (
         set /A counter+=1
         echo !counter!: %%~ni
         set deployment_builder[!counter!]=%%i
         set choice=!choice!!counter!
        )
    )

if %counter% LSS 10 (
      choice /C %choice% /M "type deployment_builder number"
      set DEPBUILDNUM=!ERRORLEVEL!
    ) else set /P DEPBUILDNUM="enter deployment_builder number: "

set DEPLOYMENTBUILDER=!deployment_builder[%DEPBUILDNUM%]!
echo %DEPLOYMENTBUILDER%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
for /f "delims=." %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d iac_*.tar.gz') do set "NameOnly=%%i"
```

This would save the left side of the name before any dot in %NameOnly%, unless you have more dots in the name like This.is.the.file.name.tar.gz In this case it would save only "This"...

Or you could use:

```
for /R %%i in (iac_*.tar.gz) do (
                                 set "NameOnly=%%i"
                                 set "NameOnly=!NameOnly:.tar.gz=!"
                                )
```

This would save the normal name in NameOnly and then remove all tar.gz occurrences form the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the last 4 characters (`.tar`)

**1.** Define `set _Variable=%%~ni`
**2.** Remove `.tar` with `set "_Variable=!_Variable:~0,-4!"`

---

```bat
@echo off 

Pause
cd .\images
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "counter=0" && set "choice="

for /R %%i in (iac_*.tar.gz) do (
     set "name=%%~ni"
     set "name=!name:~0,-4!"
     if not "!name!%%~xi" == "%~nx0" (
         set /a "counter+=1"
         echo !counter!: !name!
         set deployment_builder[!counter!]=%%i
         set "choice=!choice!!counter!"
        )
    )
    
if !counter! LSS 10 (
     choice /C !choice! /M "type deployment_builder number"
     set "DEPBUILDNUM=!ERRORLEVEL!"
    )else set /P DEPBUILDNUM="enter deployment_builder number: "

set DEPLOYMENTBUILDER=!deployment_builder["DEPBUILDNUM"]!
echo !DEPLOYMENTBUILDER!
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [DelayedExpansion (Refer: `!variables!`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)